# Openbox window manager key binds and the grave/tilde key (rc.xml)

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

I am running Debian 8 (Jessie) and trying to reconfigure the ALT-TAB window switching to ALT-[GRAVE/TILDE].

My inputrc is at

```
/usr/share/lxde/openbox/rc.xml
```

Inside is:

```
    <action name="NextWindow">
      <finalactions>
        <action name="Focus"/>
        <action name="Raise"/>
        <action name="Unshade"/>
      </finalactions>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="A-S-grave">
    <action name="PreviousWindow">
      <finalactions>
        <action name="Focus"/>
        <action name="Raise"/>
        <action name="Unshade"/>
      </finalactions>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Window switching works using this file when "grave" is replaced with "Tab" only. I have also tried "dead_grave" but that does not work either.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Running the graphical configurer lxhotkey, I receive an error message when I try binding alt + grave, that it is not a valid global hotkey.